# resignFirstResponder in Swift

Tags: uiview, swift, ios8

How can I implement it in the new language of Apple:

#### Objective-C code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
        [view resignFirstResponder];
}
```

I have tried to do so. But the keyboard does not disappear:

#### Swift code:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    self.view.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: Your objc and Swift code do different things. Did you try to port the working Objective-C implementation?

Comment: The method signature is now override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could probably go with:

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

Comment: Thanks for short answer :)

Comment: It also works for ObjC as `[self.view endEditing:YES];`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```