# in swift how to dismiss the key board

Tags: swift, keyboard, uitextfield, xcode6.1

I am wondering how to dismiss a key board if the user touches outside the `UITextField`. I am using Xcode 6.1. I added a `UITextField` to a `UIViewController` as per the below thru `ViewDidLoad()` function. Any help on dismissing the key board would be much appreciated.

```
    class PickerdemoViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate{

var textBox1 : UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {

//..................adding text box.........................//

    self.textBox1 = UITextField (frame: CGRectMake(100, 152.5, 50, 35))
    textBox1.delegate = self
    textBox1.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    textBox1.placeholder = "enter"
    textBox1.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.DecimalPad
    self.textBox1.resignFirstResponder()
    textBox1.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.Default
    self.view.addSubview(textBox1)



    super.viewDidLoad()

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [resignFirstResponder in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034786/resignfirstresponder-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a reference to the `UITextField` so make a property value like this

```
class MyClass: UIViewController {
  var textBox1: UITextField!
  ...
  // create your textfield where ever you were by assigning it to self.textBox1
}
```

Then to dismiss the keyboard you resign its as the first responder.

```
self.textBox1.resignFirstResponder()
```

**Update to dimiss keyboard**

Dismissing on return/done with the `textField` delegate method

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.textBox1.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Dismissing on a button click (custom IBAction method)

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton!) {
    self.textBox1.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: Still I have issues in dismissing it. it is not not disappearing not sure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you update your question showing how you are creating the textfield now.

Comment: `self.textBox1.resignFirstResponder()` needs to be called when you want to dismiss the keyboard either on an `IBAction` method or when hitting the enter/done button but for that you need to implement `textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool` I have updated my answer.

Comment: some reason it is not going away....using touchesBegan function  managed to make it disappear while touching out side the text box but only on the view controller...

Answer (score 0):

This will dismiss the keyboard by tapping screen. Make sure to not put it in the viewDidLoad.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {  // this func lets you close keyboard by touching screen
    self.view.endEditing(true) // this line lets you close keyboard by touching screen
}
```